Using masterwork transformation spell on broken non magical items
I am playing Pathfinder 1e and i had this thought...
If I have a non magical tool, armor or weapon and it has Broken condition. Is it possible to cast Masterwork Transformation spell on it to remove broken condition. Or will it just turn into broken masterwork item?
I think if this is possible to achieve this it would be a good way to procure good items for low level players in areas with scarce access to traders and crafter NPCs.
As far as I see in the description of Masterwork transformation spell there isn't anything that would prevent this course of action and in the description of a broken condition I also don't see anything that would prohibit this, aside form all that description of masterwork modifier doesn't go into detail on obtaining this modifier through spells, but maybe I am reaching too far with this idea...
Thanks for your time and investment.

You would create a broken masterwork item
The key section of the spell text says:

You convert a non-masterwork item into its masterwork equivalent.

That is all the spell does, there is no mention of repairing or otherwise changing the qualities or conditions applying to the item.
Note also that the spell also requires magical reagents equivalent to the cost difference between purchasing a normal item and a masterwork version of the item.  Whether this alleviates supply issues is questionable - are traders/merchants selling the magical reagents more frequently available than traders/merchants selling masterwork items?  In my experience, the main advantage of the spell is saving time - the PC buys the material component, casts the spell and instantly has the masterwork item, rather than waiting weeks for a craftsman to make a masterwork item of the type desired using the (painfully slow) Crafting rules.

I see... I didn't consider this angle. And my thought process was that since it requires "magical reagents" maybe through ways of magic it would repair item while transforming it. But your answer sounds reasonable. Thanks, I'll mark it as a solution.
